# Nativescript Vue: RadListView isn't refreshing when data changes

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a `RadListView` for a prop, `totalMovies`, which is an array.  Each movie contains an `image` field and `favorite` field.  If the `favorite` field is `false`, then an unfilled heart image shows and there's an event that fires on `tap` that changes that movie's `favorite` to true.  After clicking the heart, I see in console that it registers and I verified again with VueTools that `totalMovies` shows the movies I favorites as having `favorite: true`, but the image that shows is always the `unfilled-heart` image.  I am guessing or assuming that the RadListView is not refreshing properly?

```
<RadListView
    for="(movie,index) in totalMovies" 
    @itemTap="onItemTap($event)"
    itemHeight="80"
    :key="index"
    gridSpanCount=1
>
    <v-template>
        <FlexboxLayout class="item-row" :key="index" flexDirection="row" width="100%" height="100%">
            <Image v-if="movie.favorite" width="20" src="~/assets/images/heart-filled.png" />
            <Image v-else @tap="handleToggleFavorite(movie)" width="20" src="~/assets/images/heart-unfilled.png" />
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </v-template>
</RadListView>
```

EDIT:  Adding playground:  http://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=GNo11S&v=2

Comment: It's recommended to keep your template static, use one Image and bind src based on condition.

Comment: thanks @Manoj.  I will try that.  I actually found another workaround.  I added this in the function that toggled favorites:  `this.$refs.radListView.nativeView.refresh();` and it works.  I assume this is a poor way to handle it?

Comment: That refreshes the whole list view, so yes it may not be the best option.

Comment: @Manoj I am trying your solution and confused as to how I can do it.  `<Image @tap="handleToggleFavorite(movie)" width="20" :src="movie.favorite ? heartFilled : heartUnfilled" />` .  I have `heartFilled` as initialData on the component that has the url to that asset and `heartUnfilled` as initialData set to the url for that asset.  I don't believe I am doing this correct. 
I assume you mean to do it like this:  
`<Image @tap="handleToggleFavorite(movie)" width="20" :src="assetURL" />` and have `assetURL` be dynamic but how can that initialData `assetURL` be dynamic if it's based on loop

Comment: That looks good, if you still have issues please share a Playground sample

Comment: @Manoj ok, I just copied to a playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=GNo11S&v=2   
You can see the favorites getting added in `Favorites` tab but it's not reflecting in the current tab

Comment: Do not use ObservableArray with Vue, try simple array it works. Or use Observable with ObservableArray for change detection.

Comment: oh wow, I would have never guessed that was the issue.  Thank you @Manoj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ObservableArray** listens to changes on array index and refreshes the list view. So if you are using ObservableArray, try to update item at index using `setItem` method.

Otherwise in your case **simple array** should work as Vue can detect the changes.